# Display only one post each WEEK

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, query-posts, scheduled-posts

I have custom post type named `'NEWS'` where i already published 52 posts at a time. Now, in front i would like to display them `ONE NEWS` for `ONE WEEK`. So 52 NEWS will cover one year for me.

My Question, how can i run the query & schedule to display 1 News for 1 Week. There has no mandatory issue that for certain NEWS for certain WEEK. Simply display as a asceding/descending way for each week.

Really appreciate if anyone can help to get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What work have you done so far? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of ways to achieve this and to optimize this to make it efficient as well.

Here is just a basic idea to achieve this by using the [`offset`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) parameter in [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and using the php function [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the current week number.

- First, you should get the current week number with `date( 'W' )`. You can decide to take this as your starting point, which will be `15` this week. You can also decide to start this at 1 by deducting 15 minus 1 from the current week. As from 1st January you will need to recalculate this differently to get the correct offset. You can go and play around with this to match your needs
- Next, calculate the `offset`. The offset will be the current week minus 1 to make sure that your first offset is `0` to get the first post and `51` to get the 52nd post (last post)

Here is a sample query to start with this week at `15`; (*This is just the basics, remember to reset your query with `wp_reset_postdata()`*)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'no_found_rows' => true, 
    'offset' => (date( 'W' ) - 1)
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump( $q->posts );
```

This should give you one post from the post type `news` which will change once a week with the start of the new week

Comment: Excellent !!!! Really great effort. I was really awaiting for this type of query. You are awesome @Pieter Goosen. I believe this can solve my problem :) Thanks a million.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)